# File not found. Why not?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

Okay, I'm trying to load a file in Java using this code:

```
String file = "map.mp";
URL url = this.getClass().getResource(file);
System.out.println("url = " + url);
FileInputStream x = new FileInputStream("" + url);
```

and despite the file being in the same folder as the class it says it can't find it (yes, it **is** in a try catch block in the full code).

However, it finds another file using the same code with a different name:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("default.png");
System.out.println("url2 = " + this.getClass().getResource("default.png"));
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Why can't my code find my map.mp file?

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, url.toString() is much more efficient (and nicer) than "" + url.

Comment: Should we assume that it's throwing a FileNotFoundException?

Comment: So what gets printed out when you run this? I'm guessing the problem is that FileInputStream doesn't like URLs.

Comment: Heh, I should have refreshed the page before that last comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're trying to use a url as if it's a filename. It won't be. It'll be something starting with `file://`. In other deployment scenarios there may not be an actual file to open at all - it may be within a jar file, for example. You can use `URL.getFile()` if you really, really have to - but it's better not to.

Use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource()` - that gives you an `InputStream` directly. Alternatively, keep using `getResource()` if you want the URL for something else, but then use `URL.openStream()` to get at the data.

Comment: What was the reason the first throws FnFE end the second don't?

Answer (score 4):

`FileInputStream` takes a file name as parameter, not a URL string.

The usual way to get at the contents that a `URL` points to is with `openStream`. You can open a stream to a resource without touching a `URL` yourself with `Class`/`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` (it opens the URL within the implementation).

Alternatively, you can open **file** URLs with:

```
InputStream in = FileInputStream(new File(url.toURI()));
```

For a resource this would require that you have raw class files outside of a jar on your filesystem. JNLP (Java WebStart) has an API for opening files is a safe manner.

In general: When converting to a `String` use `toString` or `String.valueOf` to be clear about what you are doing. Also note that `String` is somewhat weakly typed, in that the type gives no indication as to the format of the data it contains, so favour the likes of `URI` or `File`.

Comment: So how can I properly load a file than? This is going into a Java Web Start Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if the file you are trying to access is being found or the intended file. Use [Sys internals File Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx). It helps monitoring which files were being accessed by the SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a space in your path? Do you see a %20? Remove that. 
Then, this will work: getResource(file) just like getResourceAsStream() does.

Spaces are evil in paths. Always avoid them.